# Bluetooth lib for python 3

Tags: bluetooth, python-3.x

I searched for lib for bluetooth programming in python and I found `PyBluez` but it is not compatible with Python 3. So is there any other free library for bluetooth programming compatible with Python 3?

Comment: The only package working for Python 3.11 was: bleak (https://github.com/hbldh/bleak)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/downloads/list) now supports Python 3.

Like the other answers state, there is inbuilt support for Bluetooth in [Python sockets](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html) (Python 3.3 and above). However, there is little to no documentation on how to actually use the sockets with Bluetooth. I wrote a [brief tutorial](http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/) so that I could refer back to it once I forget. You might find it useful.

Comment: Alas, the "AF_BLUETOOTH" option does not appear to be available on Windows.  Most disappointing.  My team has used PyBluez extensively and it works well _if_ you have a compatible setup.  The lack of maintenance is disappointing, but it's better than rolling our own.

Comment: PyBluez is no longer under active development.

Answer (score 9):

On python 3.3 there is native support!!
You can use bluetooth like a socket object

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html

Comment: @JohnCrawford claims that it doesn't work on Windows, therefore this (probably) is not cross-platform.

Comment: In Python 3.9 there is now support for Bluetooth on Windows with the native socket library. https://bugs.python.org/issue36590

Answer (score 1):

pybluez is now ported to python 3:
http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/downloads/list

br,