# Is there any Python Bluetooth Module for Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: python, module, bluetooth

I am new to python and bluetooth programming.

I know there is a python bluetooth module called bluetooth but I have read that it is only for GNU/Linux and Windows XP.

My PC has windows 7 on it. So I just wanted to know:

*"Is there any Python Bluetooth Module for Windows 7 64 bit?"*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to find any? Like google "python blootooth" ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111964/bluetooth-for-python-2-7

Comment: Yeah, I found pybluez but it says that it only works for GNU/Linux and Windows XP.

Comment: Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583362/bluetooth-lib-for-python-3

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ber. I believe I have python 3.3 so sockets should work

Comment: Windows installers for `2.7` and above versions are [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez/0.20#downloads) if you want to use pybluez.

Comment: Of course, you know that asking for libraries is off-topic for StackOverflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most popular Python Bluetooth package is [pybluez](https://pybluez.github.io/).  The project website mentions that it works on Linux and Windows XP, and that is what your wrote in your question.  You can find pre-compiled installers for Windows x32 and x64 on Chris Gohlke's web site: [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez).  In general if you need any Python to work on Windows x64, Chris's web site should be the first place you look.  For your application, there may be additional Bluetooth system configuration, but at least this should get you started.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit dated. If your looking for a version which works with windows 10, 
the version discussed in this comment worked for me with Windows 10 on an AMD machine.

https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/180#issuecomment-408235161