# How To Install PyBluez On Windows 8.1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bluetooth, terminal

I'm trying to use bluetooth with python, and the best module I've seen was `pybluez`. Right then, I tryied installing it by running `pip install pybluez`. The package was located and downloaded, but it raised an error when running `python setup.py egg_info`.

I then saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836136/is-there-any-python-bluetooth-module-for-windows-7-64-bit), where it's said that the only version of windows that `PyBluez` can be run on is Windows XP.

**So then I ask:**

- Is there a solution to the traceback ?
- Is there a way to run in on windows 8.1 ?
- Do you recommend another module for bluetooth managing? (Either builtin or third party)

*For Reference*

Command And Output:

```
C:\Users\Admin\> pip install pybluez
Collecting pybluez
  Downloading PyBluez-0.21.zip (104kB)
    100% |#####################| 106kB 8.6kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Could not find the Windows Platform SDK

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qay-hp\pybluez
```

--

```
Windows 8.1 With Python 2.7.10
```

**NOTE:** If it's easier to do this with python 3, I'm disposed to do so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's late but I install PyBluez in Windows 8.1 and Python 2.7 downloading the .exe in this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez)

Comment: Yes, I did upgrade to windows 10, but it still works!

Comment: Do not forget to run the installer as an administrator. Doing not so caused the installer to crash.